# Telepathic Rock or Meteorite on Fireplace Mantle

Tags: story-identification

I think this is from a 1950's B & W sci-fi TV series. I would have seen this on Saturday afternoon television being broadcast out of Roanoke, VA around 1958 or 1959. It predates the *The Twilight Zone* series. I seem to remember two young couples, perhaps staying in the country in a log cabin. An interesting rock or meteorite is on their fireplace mantle; I think one of the four found it. It is speaking telepathically. I believe it may have been holding the two couples captive somehow, as I seem to remember the entire episode was shot in this one cabin room.

I have checked episode guides from sci-fi series of that era with no luck (Science Fiction Theater, One Step Beyond, etc).  I did see a scene from it featured on the old "Dream On" HBO series with Brian Benben back in the '80s, a comedy show which commonly used a myriad of brief, quick outtakes from video archives to illustrate the thoughts of the Brian Benben character in each episode.

Comment: I remember this one. It's from the  original (1960's) Outer Limits series.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's the Outer Limits, either this one:

(From the [Wikipedia episode list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Outer_Limits_%281963_TV_series%29_episodes))

Season 1, Episode 9: "Corpus Earthling"

> Gerd Oswald Orin Borsten (teleplay) and Louis Charbonneau (story)
>   Aired 8 November 1963
>  Parasitic aliens, with a plan to take over
>   the human race, take refuge in a geologist's laboratory disguised as
>   rocks. Although undetected by ordinary humans, one doctor (with an
>   implanted metal plate in his skull) is able to "hear" the aliens
>   communicate with each other while they discuss their plot. Although
>   the doctor is unsure if what he hears is a delusion or not, the aliens
>   see him as a threat and set out to kill him.

Or this one:

> Season 2 Episode 6 "Cry of Silence"
>  Charles Haas Robert C. Dennis
>   (teleplay), Louis Charbonneau (story)
>  Aired 24 October 1964
>  A
>   city couple driving in the countryside makes a turn into a mysterious
>   valley road where their car hits a rock and stops working. After the
>   couple leaves their car, the wife has a slight accident in which she
>   rolls downhill and sprains her ankle. When the husband reaches her,
>   they realise they are being stalked...by tumbleweeds who appear to be
>   possessed by some form of energy. At first they attempt to keep the
>   tumbleweeds at bay with fire, but soon run out of firewood. At this
>   point they are saved by a slightly disturbed farmer named Lamont, who
>   explains that things have been awkward in the valley ever since a UFO
>   landed two weeks before, causing his farm to die out. Lamont tells
>   them he stayed merely out of curiosity, but now the weeds won't allow
>   him to leave either. The three make their way to Lamont's house where
>   they spend a frightening night surrounded by tumbleweeds first and
>   then thousands of frogs. Comes morning, they walk back to the car
>   without trouble, only to be attacked by living rocks once they get
>   there. One rock kills Lamont. The couple runs back to the house, where
>   the husband finally decides that the only way they are ever to leave
>   there is to attempt to communicate with whatever is behind all this.